# How to use Java reflections to create an instance with a constructor that accepts an interface?

Tags: java

I have the method below that helps me to create an instance of a class whose constructor takes in one argument. The problem is that I am trying to create an instance of a class whose constructor takes an interface as an argument. When I invoke the method below, arg.getClass resolves to the derived class and not the interface and hence c.getConstructor fails with NoSuchMethodException. Is it possible to use reflection to create an instance of an object that takes an interface as an argument?

```
public static <T> T getInstance(String className, Object arg)
{
  Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
  Constructor<?> ctor = c.getConstructor(arg.getClass());
  return (T)ctor.newInstance(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Lang provides the [`ConstructorUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/ConstructorUtils.html) class which has a [`getMatchingAccessibleConstructor(Class, Class[])`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/ConstructorUtils.html#getMatchingAccessibleConstructor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class...%29) method for finding accessible constructors with matching class type parameters

Example:

```
public class Examples extends Object {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Examples.class;
        Constructor<?> cons = ConstructorUtils.getMatchingAccessibleConstructor(clazz, new Class[]{B.class});
        System.out.println(cons);
    }

    public Examples (A a) {}

    interface A {}
    static class B implements A {}
}
```

prints

```
public test.Examples(test.Examples$A)
```

You can check out the source code and modify it such that you can find all constructor, accessible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, it will get the job done, but I'm not sure how "clean" it is:

```
public static <T> T getInstance(String className, Object arg) {
  Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
  Class<?>[] interfaces = arg.getClass().getInterfaces();
  Constructor<?> ctor = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length && ctor == null; i++) {
      try {
          ctor = c.getConstructor(interfaces[i]);
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {  }
  }
  if (ctor != null) {
      return (T)ctor.newInstance(arg);
  } else {
      return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `arg` cannot be the interface, it can only be an object that implements it.  Therefore the call to `arg.getClass()` will return the class of the `arg` object, not the interface that is used to match the constructor when calling `Class.getConstructor(Class... parameterTypes)`.

Given this, you'll need to write a function that does a looser match along these lines:

```
for (Constructor constructor : Class.forName(className).getDeclaredConstructors())
{
  if (constructor.getParameterTypes().length == 1 && constructor.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(arg.getClass())
  {
    return (T)constructor.newInstance(arg);
  }
}
```